# Unable to run git clone in github actions

Tags: git, macos, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I setup my password and username as follow:

```
git config --global user.email $git_email
git config --global user.name $git_username
git config --global user.password $git_password
```

where $git_email, $git_username, and $git_password point to the correct environmental variables.

```
Now when I try to run git clone I get the following error: 
Cloning into 'certificates'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured
```

The same approach works locally and in Travis CI so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 3):

`user.name` is not a username, and `user.password` does not exist.  From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for `user.name`:

> Note that the name forms of these variables conventionally refer to some form of a personal name. See git-commit(1) and the environment variables section of git(1) for more information on these settings and the `credential.username` option if you’re looking for authentication credentials instead.

That is, `user.name` should be your (human) name, not a username.

As a result, you're being prompted for a username and password, but you're getting a failure because there's no TTY on which to prompt you.  On your system, the credentials are probably already saved in your credential helper, which is why you're not seeing the prompt.

If you want to clone another repository, you should first create a personal access token and store that in your CI system's secret storage (e.g., as an environment variable called `TOKEN`).  PATs don't change when your password does, can be revoked and rotated independent of your password, and are more secure than most passwords.

Then, in your CI tool, run the following:

```
$ git config credential.helper '!f(){echo username=token; echo "password=$TOKEN";};f'
```

This will set up a credential helper to use the token that's in the `TOKEN` environment variable as your password.  Make sure that environment variable is set for your clone operation, and things should just work.